# Trigger to limit Opportunity insertion based on total amount of opportunities that day

Tags: apex, trigger

I want to show an error message if on inserting an opportunity the total of Amount field of all the opportunities inserted that day exceeds 100,000.

```
trigger LimitTotalAmountInOpportunity on Opportunity (before insert) {

    double totalamount = 0;
    for(opportunity op1 : [select Amount from opportunity where createdDate = today and createdById =: UserInfo.getUserId()]){
        totalamount += op1.amount;                      
    }

    for(opportunity op2 : trigger.new){
        totalAmount += op2.Amount;
        if(totalAmount > 100000){
            op2.addError('Total Amount Limit Exceded'); 
        }  
   }   
}
```

## I am getting a run time error on line " totalamount += op1.amount; "

## Error :

> LimitTotalAmountInOpportunity: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.NullPointerException: Argument cannot be null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `op1.amount;` field has a value.

Otherwise add a null check before adding value into `totalamount` in both the `for` loops

```
if(op1.amount != null)
    totalamount += op1.amount;
```